# When using react navigation, I can't hide the tab bar in a full screen modal

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How do you hide the tab bar in a full screen modal using react navigation?

I have a standard tab navigation a standard modal.

```
const MapStack = StackNavigator(
{
    Map: {
      screen: MapScreen,
    },
    MyModal: {
      screen: ModalScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

export default TabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Map: { screen: MapStack },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the props to your screen's `navigationOptions` as

```
 Map: {
        screen: MapScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarVisible: false
        }
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

**After you write code follow this step**

```
navigationOptions: { tabBar: { visible: false } }
```

***I believe it will help you.***

Answer (score 0):

In `react-navigation version 6.x`
**[The tabBarVisible option is no longer present](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/#the-tabbarvisible-option-is-no-longer-present)​** Since the the tab bar now supports a `tabBarStyle` option, they have removed the `tabBarVisible` option. You can achieve the same behavior by specifying `tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' }` in options.